# Ads are showing when I build a apk in unity but when app bundle is uploaded on playstore, it doesn't

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I recently launched a game in unity which I uploaded on playstore. I was able to display ads when I just built an apk from the app but when I upload the app bundle on playstore and playstore launched that update, the ads stop displaying. My admob account is approved and my individual app's approval status is also 'Ready'.
I am not able to understand why my game is not displaying any ads as it should be working. All the ad ids are correct and it works fine in the normal apk. I am seeing proper ads.

Can someone help me please.

My AdManager Script

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using GoogleMobileAds.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class MediationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Ad_IDs
    public string app_Id;
    public string banner_Id;
    public string nativeBanner_Id;
    public string interstitial_Id;
    public string rewardedVideo_Id;

    public static MediationManager Instance;
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private BannerView nativebannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    #endregion



    private void Awake()
    {

        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
            print("again");
        }
        else
        {
            print("not again");

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    void Start()
    {

        MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);
        //RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration =
        //   new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        //   .SetTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TagForChildDirectedTreatment.True)
        //   .build();
        //MobileAds.SetRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(HandleInitCompleteAction);


    }



    private void HandleInitCompleteAction(InitializationStatus initstatus)
    {

        MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() =>
        {
            //RequestBanner();
            RequestInterstitial();
            RequestAdmobRewarded();
            // RequestNativeBanner();
            //ShowTopBanner();
        });
    }


    #region Request Ads
    public AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    }
    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("adsRemoveCount") <= 2)
        {
            // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
            if (this.interstitial != null)
            {
                this.interstitial.Destroy();
            }

            // Create an interstitial.
            this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_Id);

            // Register for ad events.
            this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnAdLoaded;
            this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
            this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += this.HandleOnAdOpened;
            this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnAdClosed;
            // this.interstitial. += this.HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

            // Load an interstitial ad.
            this.interstitial.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
        }

    }
    public void RequestBanner()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("RemoveAds") == 0)
        {
            // Clean up banner ad before creating a new one.
            if (this.bannerView != null)
            {
                this.bannerView.Destroy();
            }
            // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
            this.bannerView = new BannerView(banner_Id, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);

            // Register for ad events.
            this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleAdLoaded;
            this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
            this.bannerView.OnAdOpening += this.HandleAdOpened;
            this.bannerView.OnAdClosed += this.HandleAdClosed;
            //this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleAdLeftApplication;

            // Load a banner ad.
            this.bannerView.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
            this.bannerView.Hide();
            print("Show Top Banner");
        }
    }
    public void RequestNativeBanner()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("RemoveAds") == 0)
        {
            if (this.nativebannerView != null)
            {
                this.nativebannerView.Destroy();
            }

            this.nativebannerView = new BannerView(banner_Id, AdSize.MediumRectangle, 0, 54);


            this.nativebannerView.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
            this.nativebannerView.Hide();
        }
    }
    private void RequestAdmobRewarded()
    {

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("adsRemoveCount") <= 2)
        {
            this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(rewardedVideo_Id);

            // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
            this.rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleRewardedAdLoaded;
            // Called when an ad request failed to load.
            //      this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;

            // Called when an ad is shown.
            this.rewardedAd.OnAdOpening += HandleRewardedAdOpening;
            // Called when an ad request failed to show.
            this.rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
            // Called when the user should be rewarded for interacting with the ad.
            this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
            // Called when the ad is closed.
            this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;


            // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
            this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Banner callback handlers

    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.LoadAdError);
    }

    public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Interstial callback handlers 
    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: "
                            + args.ToString());
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");

    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
        RequestInterstitial();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);

    }

    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);

    }
    #endregion 

    #region AdmobRewarded_Ad callback handlers

    public void HandleRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad event received with message: "
                             + args.AdError.GetMessage());
        // RequestAdmobRewarded();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdOpening(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdOpening event received");
        // RequestAdmobRewarded();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
            "HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow event received with message: "
                             + args.AdError.GetMessage());

        //  RequestAdmobRewarded();
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardedAdClosed event received");
        RequestAdmobRewarded();
        
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("adsRemoveCount"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("adsRemoveCount", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("adsRemoveCount") + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("adsRemoveCount", 1);
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region  Ads Call Function


    public void ShowAdmobInterstial()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("adsRemoveCount") <= 2)
        {
            if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
            {
                interstitial.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                RequestInterstitial();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ShowAdmobRewardedVideo()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("adsRemoveCount") <= 2)
        {
            if (this.rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            {
                this.rewardedAd.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                RequestAdmobRewarded();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Maybe when you initialise your ad manager, it might have a flag for test ads or not?

Comment: I have added my script to the question.

Comment: When you tested it on your device was it an Android or iOS and also on which platform was not working after you published it?

Comment: I built the apk file and ran it on my android phone and it worked fine and real world ads were loading. After Publishing the app bundle, I am not able to see the ads. I ran logcat and this error was coming - GoogleMobileAds.Api.AdFailedToLoadEventArgs
Also, once the app bundle with the same version code is published and accepted by playstore, the ads in the apk with the same version code also stop showing. I noticed this right now.